# Using multiple conditions in Chef only_if guard

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, cookbook

I am using the following chef resource:

```
execute 'run_command' do
  command "chkconfig service on"
  only_if node['platform_version'].to_i == 6, 5
end
```

Please let me know if only_if guard is used in correct fashion

Comment: More `only_if %w(6 5).include?(node['platform_version')`. It's just a ruby test, so if you wish to do a X == 5 or 6, the best idea is to make an array of [5,6] and test if this array include the actual platform_version value.

Comment: do you think it might give wrong result if the platform version is 6.5. should i instead do `only_if %w(6 5).include?(node['platform_version'].to_i)`

Comment: 6.5 when called with to_i will return 6, so yes, it will be better.

Answer (score 0):

The ruby commands in the guard block should be enclosed in {}. Also note that any ruby code inside the guard block will be executed at the converging phase i.e. run-time. I had a similar scenario and based on tensibai's comment above, I just used a array with pre-included values to be checked for the ubuntu version.

```
execute "apt-get-update" do
  command "apt-get update"
  ignore_failure true
  notifies :install, 'package[ntp]', :immediately
  not_if {[16.04, 18.04].include?(node['platform_version'].to_f) && (node['packages'].keys.include? "ntp")}
  #not_if {(node['packages'].keys.include? "ntp")}
end
```

So for your scenario, I believe that the guard-block would be something like

```
execute 'run_command' do
    command "chkconfig service on"
    only_if {[5, 6].include?(node['platform_version'].to_i)} 
end
```